How can I use ggplot2 to plot 12 horizontal lines with 3 values on each line?
I have a dataframe of 12 categories, 3 audiences, and corresponding values, arranged "long" so that I can (theoretically) use facet_wrap along the categories and plot all three audience values on each category line. The data look like this:



Category
Audience
Value




Category_1
Audience_1
5.5


Category_2
Audience_1
4.3


Category_3
Audience_1
6


Category_1
Audience_2
6.5


Category_2
Audience_2
2.6


Category_3
Audience_2
3.7



...so on and so forth, with again, 12 total categories and 3 total audiences.
I want a geom that will plot the values for each audience along a line of each category, so that there would be 12 total horiztonal lines, with 3 values plotted on each line; theoretically the code would look something like:
data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Value, y = Audience)) +
    geom_???() +
    facet_wrap(~Category)

Is there any geom_ that can plot this as requested? Thanks!
So far I've only been able to arrange the data as I indicated and search for a geom that could perform the plotting, but I was unable to find a geom that does what I want.

To draw a line, we use geom_line. Note that with a categorical x-axis, we need to set the group appropriately.
ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Value, color = Audience, group = Audience)) +
  geom_line()


Or perhaps, you want the plot like this (I only have two audiences):
ggplot(df, aes(x = Audience, y = Value, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Category)


Since you talk about horizontal lines, I don't think it makes sense to place Value on the x-axis and Audience on the y-axis.
